# https connections with curl/wget fail on newer Raspberry Pi OS version

Tags: ssl, curl, https, raspberry-pi, wget

I use a Perl script (using system commands curl/wget) to fetch some data from my old Linksys WRT54GL router via https.

curl works fine on a rather old Raspbian (now Raspberry Pi OS) distribution ("Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"), but the latest do not work anymore. I assume it is because of an old cipher. Recent PC Linux distributions still work.

"openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.1:443" on Ubuntu: TLSv1/SSLv3, RC4-SHA

Now I am wondering how I can get it working again (still using https, not http). With additional command line arguments (like "--ciphers" or "--secure-protocol") I did not succeed; also copying old binaries to the new system did not work out.

`$ curl --insecure https://192.168.1.1`

"Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)": fails

curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

"Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)": fails

curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

`$ wget --no-check-certificate -O /dev/null 'https://192.168.1.1/'`

"Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)": works

"Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)": fails

GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.

GnuTLS: received alert [40]: Handshake failed

Any ideas how to get it work, please?

Many thanks in advance,

Holly

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/889631/curl-fails-to-retrieve-https-content-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-byte

Comment: Thanks for the hint!
Indeed, old version works:
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2015-02-17/2015-02-16-raspbian-wheezy.zip
`curl 7.26.0 (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3`
or self compiled on same OS:
`curl 7.78.0 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.78.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.7
R`
Unfortunately not transferable to new OS distribution:
`error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0`
although tried to compile statically
`./configure --disable-shared --with-openssl`

Comment: It looks like WRT54GL uses an older version of SSL/TLS (possibly SSL3?) and it probably uses antiquated ciphers as well.  Curl, wget, and openssl on the newer r-pi all rely on underlying libraries for SSL/TLS, and these underlying libraries may not have support for the antiquated protocols and ciphers that the WRT54GL uses.  It may be a small feat to get curl, wget, or openssl working with these older protocols/ciphers on your newer r-pi.

Comment: You are right, it seems to be "TLSv1/SSLv3, RC4-SHA". Copying old files seems to be not a good idea because of the shared libraries. I also did not succeed with compiling curl without shared libraries.
Actually it's not a Rasperry OS issue, it works on Linux Mint 18.3 but not on Linux Mint 20.
I would be curious whether there is some easy way to get it work (like compiling a statically linked version) without compromising security even more (like switching to http).

Comment: @mti2935+ in openssl below 1.1.0, when the `New` line says `TLSv1/SSLv3` that does NOT necessarily mean the _protocol_ used is either of those; there should be a separate line just under `SSL-Session` that says `Protocol`. Though in this case one of them does seem likely. OP: did you recompile only curl, or also OpenSSL _and_ use that? If the latter, you should ./config[ure] it with no-shared and enable-weak-ssl-ciphers. OP: did you selfcompile only curl, or OpenSSL _and_ curl using it? If the latter, I think it should work to configure OpenSSL with no-shared enable-weak-ciphers ...

Comment: ... Alternatively, if you'd be willing to switch to Java, that still (in j16) has the _code_ for everything back to SSLv3; obsolete protocols and weak ciphers are default-disabled by security properties, but you can override that at runtime, and I am able to successfully make a connection to one of my archived test versions of OpenSSL 1.0.0 using SSLv3 'EXP-RC4-MD5' (i.e. TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5) which is even worse than your device.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, Java could be an alternative option.
I tried several things: compiling OpenSSL `./config no-shared enable-weak-ssl-ciphers`
and compiling curl:
`./configure --disable-shared --with-openssl=/home/pi/openssl-1.0.1u`
`make` (required packages _libssl-dev libssl1.0-dev_).
Configuration looks good, but it seems a different OpenSSL version is used:
`curl -V`: _curl 7.78.0 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.78.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2q zlib/1.2.11_.
It also does not work, same result without specifying OpenSSL library:
`./configure --disable-shared --with-openssl`.

Comment: Finally I succeeded by compiling curl on an old wheezy distribution:
`./configure --disable-shared --with-openssl`
`make`.
Although I tried to link statically, two libraries were required: _libcrypto.so.1.0.0, libssl.so.1.0.0_.
`curl -V`: _curl 7.78.0 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.78.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.11_

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to all contributors!
Apparently the problem was caused by not any more supported legacy cyphers.
I did not succeed compiling a working version by using `--with-openssl=/home/pi/openssl-1.0.1u`.
Finally I found a way by compiling curl on an old wheezy distribution:
`./configure --disable-shared --with-openssl`
`make`
Although I tried to link statically, two libraries were still required: *libcrypto.so.1.0.0, libssl.so.1.0.0*.
`curl -V`: *curl 7.78.0 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.78.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.11*
This version can be successfully run on newer OS versions (tested on Raspbian Stretch 9.13, Buster 10.10).